# JavaScript statement execution order

Tags: jquery, validation

In the following code how can I still have the second and third statement executed even if the first one returns false?

```
// so in this one if Required fails I dont get the email error :(
function validate() {
    if (checkRequired(myForm.requiredElements)
        && checkEmail(myForm.emailInputs)
        && checkTelephone(myForm.telInputs)) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: As the answer was nice and useful I simplified the question so other users find and understand it easier.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the single-ampersand version of and, it doesn't shortcircuit like the double-ampersand one.

```
function validate() {
    if (checkRequired(myForm.requiredElements)
        & checkEmail(myForm.emailInputs)
        & checkTelephone(myForm.telInputs)) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: appclay you're a star. wait for 7min to get your tick. thanks mate